# Solução para escanear documentos pelo browser

Tags: javascript, html5, scanner

Quero que usuários `digitalizem documentos` direto do **browser** pra em seguida upar pro **servidor**.

Encontrei **APIS** que fazem isso mas todas são pagas e as licenças ***caríssimas*** !

Alguém consegue apresentar uma solução ? Mesmo que o cliente tenha que instalar algum **plugin** ou algo que apresente o output de um **scanner** como se fosse de uma **webcam** .

Segue um **fiddle** que apresenta algo semelhante ao que quero: [fiddle de captura de imagem pelo browser](http://jsfiddle.net/codepo8/agaRe/4/) (rodou no mozila)

```
                          Exemplo que fiz usando o Fiddle
```

[image: Exemplo que fiz usando o Fiddle]

Essa seria uma **solução** que atende bem e parece ser mais fácil de ser alcançada, mas claro que se houver um **plugin** que acessa direto o **scanner** melhor ainda.

Comment: emular webcam a partir de um scanner? não seria o contrário?

Comment: @DanielOmnie é isso mesmo, semelhante aos programas que emulam uma webcam a partir da tela do usuário, se houver algum que transmita um " buffer " de documentos escaneados como se fossem input de uma webcam seria possível acessa-los do browser usando a API de  WebRTC

Comment: não entendi.. se tem um scanner, para quê precisa de uma webcam para simular um scanner? rsrsr.. conecte-se diretamente no scanner.

Comment: @DanielOmine sem a instalação de plugins o browser não tem acesso direto a vários periféricos incluindo um scanner, mas tem acesso direto a webcam pelo html5(API WebRTC).

Comment: então quer disponibilizar isso para um acesso publico, certo?

Comment: @DanielOmine preciso de algo semelhante a isso http://jsfiddle.net/codepo8/agaRe/4/ código que resolve em um pc que tiver uma camera emulada com o documento escaneado de output ( aqui so rodou no firefox ) .

Comment: pois isso que perguntei.. a descrição está ao contrário. `algo que emule uma webcam a partir de um scanner`. Deveria ser "algo que emule um scanner a partir de uma webcam"

Comment: @DanielOmine vou tentar melhorar !

Comment: @DanielOmine acho que o que ele disse está certo. Ele quer que o scanner apareça como webcam pro browser pegar pela API. O Scanner é verdadeiro (físico), mas vai "simular" o protocolo de uma webcam.

Comment: Resolveu seu problema?

Comment: ainda não @durtto ;/

Comment: A pergunta é muito boa. Infelizmente eu não sei responder, mas a minha intuição me diz que se as licenças de produtos existentes são assim tão caras (pelo que eu vi numa Googlada rápida, da ordem de 1500 dólares pra cima), é sinal de que não é uma tarefa trivial de ser realizada. Se você tem controle da máquina dos seus clientes (isto é, se o uso está mais pra uma Intranet do que pra Internet), você pode pensar em construir um cliente próprio. Detalhes aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3504353/2896619

Comment: @LuizVieira também fui percebendo isso ! Minha principal expectativa era que existisse programa que fizesse isso .Se fosse criar na mão , esse tutorial ensina como emular uma camera http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437617/DirectShow-Virtual-Video-Capture-Source-Filter-in , no caso esse usa a captura da tela e existem vários projetos open source que comunicam com o scanner http://www.findbestopensource.com/tagged/twain . Se pegar a parte de captura de um projeto open source de um scanner e jogar em cima desse tutorial acho que funcionaria. Mas pro meu nível de programação é mto difícil !

Answer (score 2):

Os scanners modernos possuem recursos diversos e fornecem APIs. Infelizmente as APIs não possuem um protocolo padrão pois cada fabricante define um padrão próprio. Para desenvolver algo como pretende é gambiarra e mesmo que consiga, pode não durar muito tempo. Talvez nem seja usado. Um investimento "grande" e complexo para algo que pode não ser útil ou retornar o investimento devido a tendência de que a curto ou médio prazo os dispositivos poderão prover um padrão univerval em suas APIs.

Contudo, isso é opinião pessoal. Para entender melhor, pesquise sobre os dispositivos compatíveis com o TWAIN: http://twain.org/scannerdriverdevelopers/specification-and-tools.html

O TWAIN é uma NPO (Non profit organization), ou seja, uma organização sem fins lucrativos. Isso é um forte atrativo e motiva aceitação global.

Se realmente pretende desenvolver tal solução, o caminho é por aí pois diversos fabricantes já adotaram. Mas não se iluda pois o mercado muda da noite para o dia. Pode acontecer que "amanhã" surja um padrão que pode ser melhor aceito que o TWAIN.

Se espera por uma resposta onde pode copiar e colar códigos prontos e ver tudo funcionando sem esforço algum, esquece. Não é uma tarefa trivial e, quem já desenvolveu soluções não fornecerá de graça, ainda mais em foruns e sites de perguntas e respostas.

Comment: Concordo Daniel . Minha maior esperança ao fazer a pergunta que era que já existisse algum plugin ou programa ( como o manycam que permite selecionar diferentes fontes pra serem o 'output' da cam emulada) que fizesse isso . Desenvolver tudo parece ser complicado e provavelmente teria que gastar muito tempo estudando o protocolo  . Achei apps open source que comunicavam com o scanner e sondei o código, mas tava difícil de entender . Então como não sou nenhum ninja em programação e não achei API , plugin nem nada open source p facilitar o desenvolvimento acho que vai ficar pra próxima .

Answer (score 1):

Não existe forma simples de se desenvolver uma espécie de projeto destes! Apenas se você contar com a câmera de um smartphone ao invés de um scanner realmente dito!

Você, em um projeto destes, terá problemas com drivers de scanners e até com a compatibilidade do recurso com certos browsers.

Caso você opte por tentar continuar com este projeto focando em scanners, você deveria pesquisar tecnologias que habilitassem o uso do scanner no website como algum script em Javascript, Python, PHP e etc, ou pegar a câmera do smartphone que a integração é bem mais simples.

Comment: Isso sem falar de drivers de scanner, compatibilidade com dispositivos mobile, custo de investimento nessa tecnologia e dezenas de erros que podem ocorrer nesse tipo de aventura.

Answer (score 0):

Já precisei fazer isso e a única maneira que encontrei foi criando um componente activex e instalando no browser.

Pela complexidade o meu cliente desistiu desse processo e optamos por um simples campo de upload.

Mas o caminho é esse, criar um componente activex em c# mesmo, instalar no browser aí sim você consegue esse processo.

Boa sorte

Comment: Hoje, em 2016, ainda temos que usar várias bibliotecas por causa de incompatibilidades dos navegadores e nenhum cliente (não técnico) iria compreender que é mais fácil criar um sistema que funcione em um navegador do que um que funcione em vários. Imagina o que seria criar e manter essa solução para vários scanners/drivers/OS/navegadores/dispositivos, insano.